# Webpack vs create react app

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, webpack, babel

Недавно начал изучение Webpack я понимаю что Webpack имеет много полезных фишек но я не понимаю зачем в ручную устанавливать babel, loader, react, react-dom   затем разобраться с package.json если вместо этого просто можно использовать create react app и все он будет сделать вместо нас?

Comment: CRA используется только в учебных целях, как минимум можно вспомнить что в CRA настроить webpack можно после npm run eject, а после eject к примеру не будет обновлятся npm пакеты и еще много чего. Вывод такой - если нужно изучить новую либу для react и нет готового webpack конфига (и не только его зачастую) то лучше CRA у него уже все настроено и не надо напрягаться. Для продакшина настраивают свой webpack.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ а что такое продакшн?